# cakephp2.5.1 Redirected to {app_folder}/{app_folder} after "isAuthorized" returned false

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am trying to authorize users depending on the type of the users(i.e. student,admin,staff), and here is the code which I have written in `AppController.php` .

```
public function isAuthorized($user = null) {
    // Any registered user can access public functions
    if (empty($this->request->params['admin']) && empty($this->request->params["staff"])) {
        return true;
    }
    if(isset($this->request->params["staff"])){ 
        return (bool)($user["type"]==="staff" || $user["type"]==="admin");
    }
    // Only admins can access admin functions
    if (isset($this->request->params['admin'])) {
        return (bool)($user['type'] === 'admin');
    }
    // Default deny
    return false;
}
```

After the login as "*student*", I typed `localhost/kit-web/admin` in the address bar in order to make sure that "*student*" has no access right to admin pages. But strangely, the webpage was redirected to `localhost/kit-web/kit-web`. And this caused `missing Kit-webController.php` error. If any user has an access right to a certain page, then everything is working fine.
 I am guessing that one possible reason is I have installed CakePHP using composer, so the directory configuration is different from the unzipped one. However, I have configured the location of `ROOT`, `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH`, APP_DIR, following the cakephp tutorial. 

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by myself. 
Reading the core source files of CakePHP, I realized that if the field "unauthorizedRedirect" is not specified, AuthComponent redirects to "/{app directory}" (i.e. $this->redirect("/{app directory}") by default. $this->redirect("/{app directory}") does not redirect the page to "/" because {app directory} is regarded as controller name. I am not sure whether this is bug or not. But I hope this helps if anyone is struggling with the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure, but don't you have to set the redirect values in the Controller? I settet things like that in the $component var.